# If cell contains text from a range of other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a project where the aim is to categorize spending on bank statements based on their description. Bank statements are uploaded onto an excel spreadsheet each month, which then should look at the description of each spend and assign it to a category.

There are 75 spend categories listed out in a row, and under each category there is a list of text against which the description of the spends on the bank statement needs to be matched. If the description **contains** text from a cell, the function should say which category that particular cell is under.

`$K$3:$CG$3` is where I have the names of the categories
`$K$4:$CG$502` is where I have the list of all the identifying text for each of the categories
C is the column in which the descriptions from the bank statements are

I have come up with the below formula, which works fine however if I expand it to the full range of identifiers (replace `$K$4:$CG$4`with `$K$4:$CG$502` in SEARCH function) it fails.

```
={INDEX($K$3:$CG$3,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$4:$CG$4,C6)),0))}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

The table is found on this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-Ufrf4QshYUdP1fVGXs0nKhiFeOmMqC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108978672740456393875&rtpof=true&sd=true). Column D is the expected outcome once the SEARCH function is expanded as in Column E, which currently arrives to N/A. "nnnnn" values in columns K to CG are dummy values and will be populated by users.

Comment: A clear example would help.

Comment: Text in a table would be more useful that a screenshot - some won't do typing if you post an image, give us something to copy & paste.

Comment: Thank you.  I have uploaded the excel file onto the link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: No there won't be multiple matches. All input in '$K$4:$CG$502' will be unique. But the challenge is to expand from a single row ($K$4:$CG$4') to the full range ($K$4:$CG$502').

Comment: That is just perfect. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @TonyFiante I have shared the workbook in the `Answer` feel free to download! And since its an `Answer` & worked for you you may accept the same an **Accepted Answer** as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **`INDEX()`**, **`AGGREGATE()`** & **`COLUMN()`** Function, you may try this formula,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula in cell **D3**

```
=INDEX($K$3:$CG$3,
AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(Control!$K$4:$CG$502)-COLUMN(Control!$K$4)+1)/
(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Control!$K$4:$CG$502,C3))),1))
```

And Fill Down! **[Workbook_Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cg2vPC_t4W_XUV_sp?e=goTXGv)**